# Element not reachable error when trying to enter values into search field

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am unable to send keys to a searchable dropdown. I can expand the dropdown using:

```
(//*/label[contains(text(),'Country of company registration')]/following-sibling::div//span[3]/span).click();
```

But when I try to send some keys to the search field I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div class="Select-input"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Xpath I'm using for search field "Select-input" is:

```
//*/label[contains(text(),'Country of company registration')]/following-sibling::div//span/div[2]
```

I've also tried to send text to "Select-value" but I get a similar error. Xpath for "Select-value" is:

```
//*/label[contains(text(),'Country of company registration')]/following-sibling::div//span/div[1]
```

Full object:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class=" form-control-label" for="countryCode">Country of company registration</label>
<div class="Select Select--single is-clearable is-searchable has-value">
<div class="Select-control">
<span id="react-select-12--value" class="Select-multi-value-wrapper">
<div class="Select-value">
<span id="react-select-12--value-item" class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true">United Kingdom</span>
</div>
<div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
<style>input#undefined::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style>
<input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-12--value" value="" style="width: 19px; box-sizing: content-box;"/>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: "Larsseit",sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"/>
</div>
</span>
<span class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value" aria-label="Clear value">
<span class="Select-clear">×</span>
</span>
<span class="Select-arrow-zone">
<span class="Select-arrow"/>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

*Apologies for the formatting.

Edit: I do not believe my question is a duplicate of the one suggested. I have put lengthy waits and also an explicit wait to ensure the dropdown has expanded. I think the problem might be due to the dynamic nature of the dropdown and hence not being able to get an accurate xpath. This is just a guess. Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe my question is a duplicate of the one suggested. I have put lengthy waits and also an explicit wait to ensure the dropdown has expanded. I think the problem might be due to the dynamic nature of the dropdown and hence not being able to get an accurate xpath. This is just a guess. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to `sendKeys()`?

Comment: Why are you trying to send your keys to <div>? I believe the real element where the text should appear is not div. Try to send keys to <input> element.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be in that you are not trying to do the input in the input element, but in the div element.

Could you try:

```
//input[@role='combobox']
```

And let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It was late and I couldn't figure out the xpath.